# Not able to execute delete command in Cypher Query in embedded neo4j database from java progrmming

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to delete Relationship between two node from neo4j database using Cypher Queries from Java 
Programming below is my code :

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );
engine.execute( "Start n= node(*) delete n" );
```

But it gives error as following:

```
Exception in thread "main" expected return clause
"Start n= node(*) delete n"
                  ^
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.parser.v1_7.CypherParserImpl.parse(CypherParserImpl.scala:66)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.CypherParser.parse(CypherParser.scala:44)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.getOrElseUpdate(LRUCache.scala:31)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:55)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:52)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:63)
```

But when I try to return all node this query is execute:

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );
engine.execute( "Start n= node(*) return n" ); this query return all node.
```

Above problem occur only with delete command...
Can anyone give me suggestion how I delete node and relationship using Progrmming in java.

Comment: What version are you using? It seems that you use an old version (pre 1.8) that doesn't support updates yet. From java you can also get all relationships of a node, delete them and then delete the node.

Comment: hi Michael i am using neo4j 1.7.2, i want to delete Relationship between two node my graphical database as:
Abhi-(Memberof)->computer,Abhi-(Memberof)->English and Abhi-(Memberof)->Java like that, means one node have same relationship with different node now i want to delete specific relationship between node like Abhi-(Memberof)->computer from java Progrmming

Answer (score 0):

Common issue : Neo4j won't delete the node if it still has a relation.
If you do this :

```
Start n= node(*) optional match (n)-[r]-() delete n,r
```

this will help for this case.